# Show spinner not working with Chrome jQuery Mobile

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile

How can I make this work but with the Chrome browser?

```
function doWork() {
    $.ajax({
        beforeSend: function () {
            $.mobile.loading("show", {
                text: "Working...",
                textVisible: true
            });
        },
        type: "POST",
        url: "ajax.jsp",
        cache: false,
        async: false,
        dataType: "text",
        data: {
            id: foo
        }
    })
}
```

Comment: Really difficult to say without a bit more code. It might be a CSS issue or your 'hide spinner' is called to quickly... Can you make a [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Comment: Doesnt matter if I don't "hide" it after, it will never show up in chrome. Ok I'll try and make a fiddle...

Comment: Hmm, strange.. seems to work, but then jsfiddle is using jqm 1.3.0 http://jsfiddle.net/YL9PP/

Comment: add `beforesend` to ajax call `$.ajax({ beforesend: doWork(), });` as in this demo http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Yymp3/

Comment: Works perfect in Firefox, but not showing in chrome... I will try and add $(document).on("pagecreate", function () { also

Comment: Not working in Chrome :(

Comment: Works flawlessly on chrome (desktop), and tested on iPhone Safari. Please post `pagecreate` function and whether you're placing it in head. Make sure you add page id to `pagecreate`, e.g. `.on("pagecreate", "#pageID", function()`.

Comment: <head></head> <script>$(document).on("pagecreate", "#start", function () ... </script>

Comment: but the function that calls ajax (dummyAjax) is in a JS file, wich is included in <head>

Comment: I've tried beforeSend, just to print out to the console.log. Same behaviour in FF and Chrome, but no spinner is showing in chrome still... This drives me nuts!

Comment: @Omar Where should I place the page id? I have 5-6 pages

Answer (score 1):

In webkit based browsers, I remember a timing issue, try using a setInterval like:

```
var tim = setInterval(function(){
    $.mobile.loading("show", { text: "Working...", textVisible: true });
    clearInterval(tim);
},1);
```

Comment: Ah, this I must try... I've seen some code when there is a interval of just 0, or 1 and didn't know it was a workaround

Comment: Yes, I'm searching a doc on the reason why

Comment: The spinner appears, but after the ajax call... same thing with FF. I've set async to false

Comment: updated the question with your code... Dosn't work :(

Answer (score 0):

Did you also add the right CSS?

```
http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.0/jquery.mobile-1.4.0.min.css
```

I've added JQM 1.4.0 and the CSS (1.4.0) as an external resource to your JSFiddle and it seems to be working - [Updated JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YL9PP/2/).

Comment: Yes I use jquery.mobile-1.4.0.css"